# Poisson-Binomial distribution approximated by binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am looking for strategies how to approximate [poisson-binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution) (PB) via the binomial (B) distribution.
I have seen a few papers [[Ehm91](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016771529190170V),Roos01,LeCam59] on them.

The papers uses total variation and arithmetic means. I am interested in upper bounding the CDF of PB.

I ran simulations for more than a day comparing $F_{PB}(k,n;\mathbf{p})$ and $F_{B}(k,n;p_g)$ where $p_g$ is the *geometric mean* (instead of the usual arithmetic mean) of the vector of $\mathbf{p}\in[0,1]^n$ with random. Throughout my simulations, with random $\mathbf{p}$ and various $n\leq 15$ (max acceptable runtime for my computer). It is always $F_{PB}(k)\leq F_{B}(k)$ for all $k\in[0,n]$.

It is simple to show the tails is true as
$
F_{PB}(n-1) = F_{B}(n-1;p_g)
$.

I have a few questions

- Is $F_{PB}(k)\leq F_{B}(k;p_g)$ true for all $k$ and $n$?

  - If so, is there a way to prove it ?
  - else, is there a counter-example ?

Thank you